# Making ontology public (in owl api) to use in other functions of the same or different classes

Tags: ontology, owl-api

I have two questions:

1. How can I make my ontology public (which is created in Protege) that I am reading in OWL API to use in other functions of the same or different classes. I only want to make my code smarter so that I dont have to declare the ontologies again and again in every function or class. I am also attaching an image to further specify my question[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVmB0.jpg)
2. I want to reason (or query) in between number of ontologies. I am able to query with the reasoners (DL and HermiT) but I am confused which one to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a local variable public and visible from multiple methods, you just declare it as a public member variable. This is achieved simply changing the access modifier to public.

DL is not a reasoner implementation, as far as I know.

HermiT implements a DL reasoner and it also supports SWRL rules. It can be used through a Protege plugin, or through code by using it as an `OWLReasoner`.

Example:

```
OWLOntology o = ...
OWLReasoner hermit= new Reasoner.ReasonerFactory().createBufferedReasoner(o);

The `hermit` object is ready to be queried now.
```

Comment: First thanks for the answer.
I know the public field but I could not insert the public field before OWLOntology interface in code,(anyways I solved this problem by passing the specific ontology in functions every time wherever I need).
Can you please provide me a basic syntax for the query writing in owl api for e.g. if I want to find an object in the whole ontology (not using the IRIs or prefixmanager) because I am confused whether to go for a keyword search which I dont prefer or to go for the whole inference results which I require.